# getting error while build android project in android studio

Tags: android

```
Error:(210) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(64) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(237) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(210) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(210) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(237) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(246) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(220) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(246) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(220) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(246) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(220) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/gumbi/Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

for example  Error:(237) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
is coming in line :

```
   <declare-styleable name="SherlockActionBar">
    <attr name="navigationMode">
        <enum name="normal" value="0"/>
        <enum name="listMode" value="1"/>
        <enum name="tabMode" value="2"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="displayOptions">
        <flag name="useLogo" value="0x1"/>
        <flag name="showHome" value="0x2"/>
        <flag name="homeAsUp" value="0x4"/>
        <flag name="showTitle" value="0x8"/>
        <flag name="showCustom" value="0x10"/>
        <flag name="disableHome" value="0x20"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="title" format="string"/>
    <attr name="subtitle" format="string"/>
    <attr name="titleTextStyle"/>
    <attr name="subtitleTextStyle"/>
    <attr name="icon" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="logo" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="divider"/>
    <attr name="background"/>
    <attr name="backgroundStacked" format="reference|color"/>
    <attr name="backgroundSplit"/>
    <attr name="customNavigationLayout" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="height"/>
    <attr name="homeLayout" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="progressBarStyle" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="indeterminateProgressStyle" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="progressBarPadding" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="itemPadding" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: any hint .. ?? please

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include more text. Comments are meant to reply to others

Comment: put your code which you tried yet.

Comment: Can you add your dependencies from build.gradle as well?

Comment: you may have errors  ---- In res folder --> values

Comment: <resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
 this line has error.. not registered element resources

Comment: to avoid an error you can redefine your attribute names like "navigationMode" to "sherlockNavigationMode" so that it wont conflict with original one

Answer (score 1):

You are using actionbarsherlock which is deprecated and will cause build errors with the newest android build tools and support libraries.

You will have to remove `com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock` from your project and use `com.android.support:appcompat`  instead. It will possibly require some refactoring but will need to be done in order to support Android 6 (ActionbarSherlock causes build errors and crashes from Android 6 and higher)

If you don't need to support the newest versions of Android you can always downgrade your build tools and support lib for now but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: You will have no advantage of using it anymore. AppCompat has all the functionality you needed from ActionbarSherlock. ActionbarSherlock will cause crashes on devices running Android 6 or higher.